# Maximizing the number of Natural Attacks on a PC?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, natural-weapon

I would like to create a character whose concept is based on having the most Natural Attacks possible.

What resources are available to add natural attacks to PC's?

Comment: This is very broad. Is there a specific concept you're going for?  You can get natural attacks from races, plenty of class abilities, templates, magic items, etc.

Comment: Well I wanted to look for a character that would use stuff like claws horns and bite and mabye others and i dont really care which race or class so what'd you reccomend

Comment: Welcome, D20Ginger. Please make sure to ask full questions that can be answered objectively or subjective questions that can be answered from experience. We've edited your question to be a little more... coherent, but if you could narrow it down further that would be better. RPG SE isn't a good place for asking for lists, so you may be redirected to forums.

Comment: This concept, character-wise, makes as much sense as wanting to master all the weapons whose name start with the letter "g". In an optimization point of view it can make sense, but you have to narrow by indicating why you want all these natural attacks.

Comment: @AnneAunyme NO you really DO NOT.  If I want to master all weapons starting with g that's a fine optimization goal in and of itself.

Comment: Do you want the most natural attacks each round or the most natural weapons?

Comment: What level are you looking for?

Comment: Im looking for most natural attacks, yes

Answer (score 2):

For a natural-attack focused character, your best bet is probably going to be using the [Synthesist](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/summoner/archetypes/paizo-summoner-archetypes/synthesist) variant of the [Summoner](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/summoner/) class.

The Summoner's big feature is the [Eidolon](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/summoner/eidolons/), a special magical being they can summon with customised features and traits. A Synthesist Summoner fuses with the Eidolon when it is summoned and may therefore use all its abilities (such as natural attacks), rather than summoning the Eidolon as a separate entity. As you gain level, you gain points which can be spent on purchasing new features, called Evolutions, for your Eidolon.

Some of the available evolutions that grant extra natural attacks are:

- Claws (1 point, but have to go on the end of a Limbs evolution, which is 2 points)
- Bite (1 point, can buy more bites if you buy more Heads, which are 2 points again)
- Gore (2 points)
- Tentacle (1 point)
- Rake (2 points - extra attacks while grappling)
- Rend (2 points, must have claws - extra damage on multiple claw hits)

It makes sense, however, to restrict yourself to a single type as much as possible, because then you can get more benefit from feats like Weapon Focus and Improved Critical.

There is a limit on the total number of natural attacks an Eidolon can have, based on your level. It starts at 3, and goes up to 7 by level 19. However, you'd have a hard time finding ways to get more than that; most playable races that offer a natural attack only offer 1 or 2 (a bite/gore or pair of claws), and creatures whose form you can easily assume at low levels tend to cap at 3 (the standard claw/claw/bite). The ability to polymorph into forms that have more natural attacks requires higher levels and I don't know of anything off the top of my head that tops the 7 that the Eidolon can do at max level.

Note, however, that the Summoner class is [not permitted in Pathfinder Society games](http://paizo.com/pathfinderSociety/rpg/additional):

> **Pathfinder Roleplaying Game: Advanced Player's Guide**
>
> ...
>
> As of 4/27/15 the summoner class in this book is no longer legal for play.

Summoners, especially Synthesist Summoners, are anecdotally frequently banned by individual GMs and groups, too, either on the grounds that they are overpowered or because they're excessively complicated. If you can play a Summoner but not a Synthesist Summoner, you could just live vicariously through your summoned Eidolon, instead. Some groups (including the PFS) that ban the Summoner may allow the [Unchained Summoner](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/unchained-classes/summoner-unchained/), which is basically a slightly nerfed Summoner with more restrictions on how you can build your Eidolon - you can't go the Synthesist route with it, but you could build an Eidolon with a similar natural attack capacity if you take the right options.

Comment: The Synthesist archetype is banned by PFS and some GMs (as is the original Summoner class).  That might not matter, but OP may need to check with their GM.  It's still a perfectly acceptable answer.

Comment: I second WeirdFrog's comment. In my experience, Synthesist (and Master) summoner are permanently denied in many games. That being said, Summoner is definitely what OP is looking for. They may be able to swing a non-Synthesist Summoner and live their goals through the Eidolon itself.

Comment: I've amended my answer to that effect. I think the Summoner approach (if permitted) also has the advantage that it's not dependent on having enough levels to put together a build; you can have your cake from level one and it just gets better as you go.

Comment: As an addendum to the whole "Summoner is often banned" thing (which has been my experience as well), the Unchained Summoner is often considered the "official" alternative. UnSummoner gets almost as many natural attacks for its eidolon as the APG Summoner. When built correctly.

Comment: The best creature to polymorph into if you want many natural attacks is the Charda (small monstrous humanoid with 5 natural attacks)

Comment: Charda is probably the one you can get access to earliest, as Monstrous Physique I is 3rd level; so you could do that effectively from 5/6th level, and at that point you are beating the Eidolon for number of natural attacks, until 9th level at least (but you're also tiny and they're not very dangerous attacks - the 4 that the Eidolon can have will be more damaging). Form of the Dragon II will net you six natural attacks, but is a 7th level spell, and only potentially outnumbers Summoner for a single level if you're a prepared caster. Plus it's a wide variety so there's less feat efficiency.